# Grails: How do I forward an entire model from one controller to another?

Tags: grails, model, controller, forward, chain

How do I pass an entire model from one controller to another without using a redirect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I struggled with this for quite a while, so decided to answer my own question...

It's quite possible with the `forward` method. Unlike the `chain` method, the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) doesn't mention the `model` attribute, but [in grails 2.1.1 at least] it is actually supported.

**In Controller One:**

```
    def model = [
        firstname:           params.firstname, 
        lastname:            params.lastname
    ]

    forward(controller:"controllerName",action:"index", model:model)
```

**In Controller Two:**

```
    render (view: "/page.gsp")
```

**In page.gsp**

```
    Welcome ${firstname} ${lastname},
    ...
```

Simple as that...

Comment: It's funny how soon we forget basic Servlet development when we start using frameworks.

Comment: @Gregg Funny, more like scary!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the whole object (which contains their own methods), refer to my answer on [Best way to pass objects between controller actions in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751211/best-way-to-pass-objects-between-controller-actions-in-grails/39642192#39642192)

The key is 1) using "chain action" in source action, 2) using chainModel in target action